# How do I log input to a Proxy service in Fuse ESB?

Tags: logging, proxy, fuseesb

I have configured a Proxy service in Fuse ESB.
I would like to log the input into the proxy. There is a log component, but I am unable to log anything other than a hardcoded message.
I have tried to log $body to get to the SOAP message, but this fails as it seems to interrupt the message being passed within my proxy (I am rerouting to another port in the ESB)
Here's my blueprint.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint"
                   xsi:schemaLocation="
                   http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd
                   http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/camel-blueprint.xsd">

              <camelContext trace="false" id="blueprintContext" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
                <route id="httpBridge">
                    <from uri="jetty:http://0.0.0.0:8282/cxf/PersonServiceCF?matchOnUriPrefix=true"/>
                    <log message="&quot;The message contains ${body}&quot;" loggingLevel="INFO" logName="OutputLog" id="OutputLog">
                        <description>logs output
            &lt;log message="&amp;quot;The message contains ${body}&amp;quot;" loggingLevel="INFO" logName="InputLog" id="InputLog"&gt;
                        &lt;description&gt;logs input&lt;/description&gt;
                    &lt;/log&gt;</description>
                    </log>
                    <to uri="jetty:http://localhost:8181/cxf/PersonServiceCF?bridgeEndpoint=true&amp;throwExceptionOnFailure=false"/>
                </route>
            </camelContext>
            </blueprint>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer FYI - 
You need to set streamCache="true" on your

Comment: Yes this is the correct. We have also a note about this in the top of the camel-jetty documentation: http://camel.apache.org/jetty